# Internet Explorer fixing and encoding link - Firefox and Chrome are not

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to understand an issue with encoding between Internet explorer, Chrome and Firefox
I have been given a URL that has '&amp;' in the URL and does not work in Chrome and Firefox as both the amps are displayed.

When I navigate to the URL in Internet Explorer 8, 9 or 10 - it removes one of the 'amps' and encodes the URL and links just fine.

If I go into the code and remove one of the amps, both Chrome and Firefox work correctly.

The issue I have is that the person who gave me this issue - gets the URL link problem in their Internet Explorer 8 - which I cannot reproduce locally.

Even if I turn off 'Send UTF-8 URLs' or change the language, I’m unable to reproduce this issue.

Is anyone able to shed some light on why Internet Explorer appears to be fixing the link for me (locally) and why Chrome and Firefox do not?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `encodeURIComponent()` i you want to encode &.

Comment: Afsa is right. In a URL for a link you don't use `&amp;`, but instead use `%26`. You can get it by using JS to run this function `element.href = "http://yoursite.com/some-page?parameters=" + encodeURIComponent('parameter1=foo&parameter2=bar')`.